# Обработка исключений. C#

Tags: c#, ооп, исключения

Зачем нам нужно ключевое слово `finally` в c# , если код после try/catch и так всегда выполняется?

Answer (score 11):

Код находящийся в блоке `finally` выполнится в ЛЮБОМ случае, то есть даже если в блоках `try-catch` содержится `return` или в блоке `catch` содержится еще один `throw`.

В таких случаях код который просто идет после блока `catch` - не выполнится.

Answer (score 4):

Код после `catch` выполняется *всегда* только в том редком случае, когда вы ловите *все* исключения (что очень не рекомендуется). Обычно вы ловите только нужные исключения, и код за catch'ем вполне имеет право не выполниться.

Answer (score 1):

finally выполняет код в любом случае, после завершения конструкций в try, и не важно будет поймано исключение или нет. Чаще всего используется для освобождения ресурсов.
catch выполняется только при возникновении исключения.

Comment: Так если исключение не ловится, у нас все равно выполняется код, который идет после try/catch, зачем что-то оборачивать в finally?